# MathJax 2.7 beta

Tags: discussion, mathjax

Today we are entering the public beta phase of MathJax v2.7 beta. A list of updates is available [on github](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues?q=is%3Aclosed+milestone%3A%22MathJax+v2.7.0%22).

As always, we will be monitoring this post for any bug reports or missing features.

#### Update

[MathJax 2.7](https://www.mathjax.org/mathjax-v2-7-now-available/) was released this Friday (October 14th), we're pointing (meta.)math.SE from beta.mathjax.com back to cdn.mathjax.com

Comment: Wooooooooooo!!!

Comment: See the [MathJax Site's post](https://www.mathjax.org/mathjax-v2-7-beta-now-available/) for a write-up concerning the changes in this version of MathJax.

Comment: The new version of MathJax seems to be incompatible with my computer (equations are showing up simply as the string of symbols used as commands). Is there any update I should make for MathJax to work?

Comment: I cannot say more on how thankful I want to express to this open source project. Without MathJax, my project WEB interface will almost be impossible to be done within a few days. As a MSE user, I also want to thank MathJax for making this site so great.

Comment: MathJax v2.7 was released on Oct 14. Thanks again to StackOverflow and everyone in the math.SE community for your help and feedback during the beta run!

Answer (score 7):

I've gotten this issue twice now, it randomly starts working every now and then. But the MathJax looks like this:

[image]

I've tried restarting chrome, clearing cookies, clearing my cache, etc... it seems to work fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

This is what the developer console shows:

[image]

I'm on Windows 10 running Chrome 52.0.2743.116 (Official Build) m (64-bit) with Javascript V8 5.2.361.49

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: The screenshot indicates that your cache is probably not clean since the TeX-AMS_HTML-full.js file is loaded with 2.6.1 in the  query string (while it should be 2.7.0-beta). Could you try clearing your cache again and restarting Chrome before trying again? Chrome sometimes doesn't clear cache properly.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Of course!  Thanks. Press F12 to open the developer console, then with the console open in the background, right click the reload button (on chrome) and select the "hard reload and clear cache" option - got it working for me. :)

Comment: Great! Glad that was all it took to get working again.

Comment: @leibnewtz have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger That did it, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the following problem:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache?