# Why doesn't MathJax show up immediately?

Tags: support, mathjax, formatting, font

When we reload a page with MathJax in it, the math format is like this for a second:

[image: Sans-Serif]

After a second it becomes the desired MathJax.

Is the intermediate format in Sans-Serif? Why doesn't MathJax show up immediately? Why does it have to first look like that and then change to the desired format while the $s are used for MathJax?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It’s because MathJax version 2 is slow.

There are faster alternatives. If Stack Exchange used MathJax V3 as previously discussed at [this question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30901/switch-to-mathjax-version-3), or used [KaTeX](https://katex.org/), then rendering would be nearly instant. Sadly, we do not, so we are stuck with waiting tens of seconds to render  pages with large amounts of math code.

Comment: It's because MathJax V2 is slower than KaTeX. MathJax V3, which has been out for several years, is of comparable speed and much more feature rich.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I edited to address your comment.

Comment: Was I right about the name of that intermediate format? Is it sans-serif?

Comment: So, a Gauss elimination of an $8 \times 8$ matrix might give you an excuse for installing another tool? :-)